# Why is AWS SES mail only bouncing from good gmail.com addresses?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, email, gmail, amazon-ses

Using a Laravel job to send email to subscribers, but suddenly all gmail.com mail is bounced back with

```
Reporting-MTA: dsn; e226-11.smtp-out.us-east-2.amazonses.com    
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist.
```

This is only happening with gmail.com mail. I have confirmed this with my own gmail.com account that goes thru okay from my own domain. It's only when sending thru SES smtp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked this:

[Gmail - Service Details](https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=1&iid=a8b67908fadee664c68c240ff9f529ab)

This should be fixed now.

"The problem with Gmail has been resolved. We apologize for the inconvenience and thank you for your patience and continued support. Please rest assured that system reliability is a top priority at Google, and we are making continuous improvements to make our systems better. If you are still experiencing an issue, please contact us via the Google Help Center.

Affected users received a bounce notification with the error "The email account that you tried to reach does not exist" after sending an email to addresses ending in @gmail.com."